# React redirect to page without constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page within my react application that declares some JavaScript functions. It is structured like this:

```
import { api } from "events";

function call() {
//.Do something
}
```

In one of these function I want to redirect to a particular page.

If I was on a page that was structured like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default class reactPage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();


  }

  render() {
}
}
```

I would redirect to a page like this:

```
this.props.router.push({
    pathname: '/pageName
})
```

But as my page does not have the react import or constructor, I cannot access `props`

My question is, is there a way I can gain access to the props object of the current page from my function?

I know I can redirect using Javascript, but this will loose all state and props so is not something I want to do.

I know there are other ways of doing this, but I am specifically asking about a redirect that will maintain all my state and props and preferably not reload the page.

Comment: You would like to redirect from inside `call` function?

Comment: @TheReason yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this function is going to be called inside of a React Component, then I think I would pass in history as an additional argument into the function that needs it. That way, you can still call `history.push('/')` or wherever you need to go. You'll just need to remember to pass in history when calling that function.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly then you can pass `props` & `path` to that function as a parameters:

```
function redirectMeToSomewhere(props, path){
  const data = {...}
  // doing some work
  // collecting data
  // and then redirect
  props.router.push({
    pathname: path,
    search: '?query=abc',
    state: { detail: data }
  })
}

// somewhere in component
...
redirectMeToSomewhere(this.props, 'stackoverflow.com')
...
```

Does it work for you?